# Multiple source items per row

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm migrating content from a Joomla SQL source. The images are stored inside of the text as inline images.

This is how my source data looks like:

```
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|    id      |  introtext                                       |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1          | <h1>...</h1><img src="...                        |
| 2          | <h1>...</h1><p>...                               |
| 3          | <h1>...</h1><img src="..."/><img src="...        |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is my Source:

```
/**
 * Source plugin for image content.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "image"
 * )
 */
 class Image extends SqlBase {

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function query() {
     $query = $this->select('jos_content', 'content');
     $query->fields('content', array(
       'id',
       'introtext',
     ));

     $query->condition('content.state', 1);

     $query->condition('content.introtext', '%<img%', 'LIKE');

     return $query;
   }

   ...
```

But this query does not produce one Row per Match, it produces one row for each source row where are at least is one image. I don't know if it's possible to process this in my migration .yml file:

```
id: image
label: Images migration
migration_group: joomla
migration_tags:
  - Images
source:
  plugin: image
  constants:
    file_source_uri: 'public://import'
    file_dest_uri: 'public://imported'
    status: 1
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
process:
  file_source:
-
  plugin: concat
  delimiter: /
  source:
    - constants/file_source_uri
    - path
  file_dest:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/file_dest_uri
        - filename
  filename: filename
  uri:
    plugin: file_copy
    source:
      - '@file_source'
      - '@file_dest'
  status: constants/status
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migrate_content
```

This configuration works only if there is one image per Migration Row, but there are multiple items per row. I would appreciate any help, thank you!